# python 3.6.5 ftputil download from URL

Tags: python, python-3.x, download, ftputil

I have a csv file that contains file paths such as: oa_package/08/e0/PMC13900.tar.gz, oa_package/b0/ac/PMC13901.tar.gz, etc.

If one were to type ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pub/pmc/oa_package/08/e0/PMC13900.tar.gz into a browser, it would automatically download the file, is there a way to replicate this behavior in python?

Previously, I have successfully used the following try/catch along with host.listdir('.') to iterate and download files from the same directory.  In this situation, I am intending to download files outside of the current working directory.

```
host = ftputil.FTPHost('ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov', 'anonymous', email)
path = "pub/pmc/"
host.chdir(path) #gets to ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pub/pmc/

outFile = outDir + file
print("retrieving file:", file)  
try:         
    host.download(file, outFile) #file is zip file
except:
    print("WARNING: File could not be downloaded")
```

The traceback error is:

```
FTPOSError: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
Debugging info: ftputil 3.4, Python 3.6.5 (win32)
```

Comment: For some reason your machine seems unable to resolve the server address. Has nothing to do with `ftputil` itself

Comment: Hmm.  Okay, thanks for the response.  I will have to do some more investigating.